# f.call(null,x) vs f(x) speed

Tags: javascript, web-services

Guys I would like a theoretical answer for this question.

I would like to know if calling **f.call(null,x)** is any possibly slower than calling **f(x)** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will be very marginally slower because of the addition property lookup (finding member `call` on function `f`).  It is very much a micro-optimization and not something that should put you off using `call()` when it's necessary.

On the other hand, I've noticed that functions created with `bind()` are slower than their unbound counterparts and also slower than using `call()`, in most browsers.  Just in case you were thinking that may be a way around any performance deficit.

Note that someone has already set up some tests for this [over at http://jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/direct-vs-call-vs-apply/2).

Comment: isn't **f(x)** simply syntax sugar for **f.call(this,x)** or am i mistaken?

Comment: @Pacerier no, it's not syntactic sugar.  Both execute an internal function known as **Call**, which isn't the same as `call()`.

Comment: @Pacerier: No. They may lead to the same internal code in the implementation being called, but the setup on the JS side is longer. See http://jsfiddle.net/FAHfq/

Comment: @Pacerier: You are free to override `Function.prototype.call` or the `f.call`. Therefore the JS runtime needs to check if there's an overridden value for `call`.

Comment: @kassens so the behavior for **f(x)** cannot be modified?

Comment: @Pacerier: only by changing the value of `f` itself.

Answer (score 5):

As [this test shows](http://jsperf.com/call-or-raw), executing the function directly, wins.

```
 function foo(x) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++);
 }

 // Tests
 foo('Bob');
 foo.call(null, 'Fish');
 foo.call(window, 'Cowboy!');
```